# Work order time duration to complete in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which contains various changes in work order states as in the following example
[image: Source Data]

I would like to segregate the above rows in to time windows as "In-Progress" to "Completed". In our above example

rows 2&3 are as "In-Progress" and Row 1 "Completed"

So result set shall be

In-Progress from "12/11/2017 05:38:48" till completed on "05/01/2018 18:01:01"

[image: Desired output]

I tried CTE, changing all not complete status as in-progress and finding the time difference. However am able to get it only for the first completed till in-progress.

any help to resolve this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, if I may paraphrase - for every "Completed" row, you want to find the earliest non-"Completed" row which "matches" (based on just `CategoryID`?) that comes after any other "Completed" row, and use that for the other datetime column to show next to that "Completed" data?

Comment: By the way, it would be much kinder to present your sample data and expected results as *text* rather than as images. You're excluding people using e.g. accessibility tools and we can't copy & paste images into SSMS to recreate your sample data and so be able to test solutions. Ideally, if you make your sample data define a table variable and then an `INSERT` to populate it (bear in mind that a single `insert` can accept multiple rows these days), it doesn't take up any more space in the question and is *directly* copyable into Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated some of your sample data<sup>1</sup> and gone with the interpretation I posted as a comment to your question, and it seems to work for the first two rows:

```
declare @sample table (categoryId int, StatusCode varchar(20), 
                       StatusChangeDateTime datetime)
insert into @sample (categoryId , StatusCode, StatusChangeDateTime) values
(147, 'Completed',       '2018-01-05T18:01:01'),
(147, 'Corrections Made','2017-12-12T06:38:48'),
(147, 'Under Review',    '2017-11-12T05:38:48'),
(147, 'Completed',       '2017-10-24T08:49:48'),
(147, 'Under Review',    '2017-05-28T17:00:03')

;With NumberedCompletions as (
    select
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY StatusChangeDateTime) rn
    from
        @sample s
    where StatusCode='Completed'
), Predecessors as (
    select
        s.*,
        nc1.rn,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION By s.CategoryId, nc1.rn
           ORDER BY s.StatusChangeDateTime) rnWithin
    from
        NumberedCompletions nc1
            left join
        NumberedCompletions nc2
            on
                nc1.categoryId = nc2.categoryId and
                nc1.rn = nc2.rn + 1
            left join
        @sample s
            on
                nc1.categoryId = s.categoryId and
                s.StatusChangeDateTime < nc1.StatusChangeDateTime and
                (nc2.StatusChangeDateTime is null or
                 nc2.StatusChangeDateTime < s.StatusChangeDateTime)
)
select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nc.CategoryID
       ORDER BY nc.StatusChangeDateTime desc) as RowNumber,
    nc.CategoryID,
    'In Progress' as PriorStatus,
    p.StatusChangeDateTime as PriorDateTime,
    'Completed' as Completed,
    nc.StatusChangeDateTime as CompletedDateTime
from
    NumberedCompletions nc
        left join
    Predecessors p
        on
            nc.categoryId = p.categoryId and
            nc.rn = p.rn and
            p.rnWithin = 1
```

I think it may be doable with fewer CTEs but this "read" the most straightforwardly for me so it's what I've gone with.

Not sure all of the `categoryId` conditions are necessary but it's the only obvious thing where we might get variance and not want to cross-match rows.

Result:

```
RowNumber CategoryID  PriorStatus PriorDateTime           Completed CompletedDateTime
--------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------- --------- -----------------------
2         147         In Progress 2017-05-28 17:00:03.000 Completed 2017-10-24 08:49:48.000
1         147         In Progress 2017-11-12 05:38:48.000 Completed 2018-01-05 18:01:01.000
```

---

<sup>1</sup>I don't need the transcription/typing practice, thanks. Notice that the sample data in my answer doesn't take up any more space than the image in your question and *mine* can be copied and pasted into SSMS because it's actually a valid script.

Comment: Thanks Damien, was very helpful!! And i will start using text output rather than images !.

Comment: Need another addition for edge scenarios where the work order is still in progress and no completion date-- can that be included as ? 
2         147         In Progress 2017-05-28 17:00:03.000 Completed <<nul>>

Comment: Just reading the comment in my Question. For every completed row would need the earliest not complete date - That's correct. If a work order is not complete at all. earliest in-progress date and completion date as null please.